# add custom data to POST

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a webpage that has 3 file inputs. There are specific fields on the form that needs to be sent when user uploads the file. I am not able to figure out how do i add custom data to my POST and how do i retrieve it back on the server. This is how my code looks like:

ASPX Page with 3 file inputs and other text boxes/dropdowns:

```
<form action="FilesUploader.ashx" method="post">

    <div id="dvNewAttachment1">
        <span>Attachment Type</span>
        <select id="ddlAttachmentType1">
            <option>T1</option>
            <option>T2</option>
            <option>T3</option>
        </select>
        <span>Description</span>
        <input id="txtDesc1" />
        <select id="ddlApproval1">
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
        <input id="fileUploader1" type="file" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <br />
    ---------------
    <div id="dvNewAttachment2">
        <span>Attachment Type</span>
        <select id="ddlAttachmentType2">
            <option>T1</option>
            <option>T2</option>
            <option>T3</option>
        </select>
        <span>Description</span>
        <input id="txtDesc2" />
        <select id="ddlApproval2">
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
        <input id="fileUploader2" type="file" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <br />
    -------------------------------
    <div id="dvNewAttachment3">
        <span>Attachment Type</span>
        <select id="ddlAttachmentType3">
            <option>T1</option>
            <option>T2</option>
            <option>T3</option>
        </select>
        <span>Description</span>
        <input id="txtDesc3" />
        <select id="ddlApproval3">
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
        <input id="fileUploader3" type="file" runat="server" />
    </div>


<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

This is how my handler looks like:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            HttpPostedFile myFile = context.Request.Files[0];

            int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[nFileLen];

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(myFile.InputStream))
            {
                br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

        }
```

As you can see i have 3 uploads and each has Attachment Type and description associated with it which i need to retrieve for each input file in my handler.

Right now i am just processing file from the first input but later i am going to loop thru the inputs and process them.

Comment: I am not able to figure out how do i add custom data to my POST and how do i retrieve it back on the server.

Comment: What do you mean by custom data?

Comment: you need to make custom uploader or try ajax uploaders

Comment: If all you want to do is get access to your inputs controls, you could use Request.Params to access them in your method above (since you have access to the HttpContext).

Comment: i am able to access input controls. I need to access dropdowns and textboxes.

Comment: Request.Form[nameOfYourControl] should give you the posted value for a given control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your handler do not receive files that you place in file uploaders then your form needs to have additional attribute like this:

```
<form action="FilesUploader.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In order to get values from dropdowns on server you need to provide a `name` attribute to them:

```
<select id="ddlApproval1" name="ddlApproval1">
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am able to access the files using context.Request.Files collection. It gives me all the 3 input controls. But I need to also get dropdowns and textboxes